# implicit conversion in java operator +=

Tags: java, compiler-errors, implicit-conversion

I've found that java compile has a non-expected behavior regarding assignment and self assignment statements using an int and a float.

The following code block illustrates the error.

```
    int i = 3;
    float f = 0.1f;

    i += f;              // no compile error, but i = 3
    i = i + f;           // COMPILE ERROR
```

- In the self assignment `i += f` the compile does not issue an error, but the result of the exaluation is an int with value `3`, and the variable `i` maintains the value `3`.
- In the `i = i + f` expression the compiler issues an error with *"error: possible loss of precision"* message.

Can someone explain this behavior.

EDIT: I've posted this code block in https://compilr.com/cguedes/java-autoassignment-error/Program.java

Comment: The Java Language Specification is where you'll find the explanation. It's freely available online.

Comment: To be fair, "Chapter 5. Conversions and Promotions" is where I would have (and have) looked before stumbling on this question; chapter 15 does not even show up on the first page looking for "Java implicit narrowing conversion". Not finding the information was not necessarily a sign of not searching, and your comment didn't help in any way

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2

The Java Language Specification says:

> A compound assignment expression of the form `E1 op= E2` is equivalent to `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))`, where `T` is the type of `E1`, except that `E1` is evaluated only once.

So `i += f` is equivalent to `i = (int) (i + f)`.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that the explicit `i+f` fails because of [Narrowing primitive conversion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3). While in the first case the conversion on the right side passes because it is done according to [Compound Assignment rules.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)