# Character arithmetic in Java

Tags: java, math, char

While playing around I met something, that seems strange to me:

The following isn't valid Java code:

```
char x = 'A';
x = x + 1;    //possible loss of precision
```

because one of the operands ist an integer and so the other operand is converted to integer. The result couldn't be assigned to a character variable ... while

```
char x = 'A';
x += 1;
```

is valid, because the resulting integer is - automatically - converted to character.

So far so good. This seems clear to me but ... why is the following valid Java code?

```
char x;
x = 'A' + 1;
```

Comment: @Sotirios Many thanks for the very quick answer. Things are clearer now to me ...

Comment: @sol4me: thank you for the 'final character' hint ...

Comment: @Alboz: Initially I did not know how to do this. Now it's done ...

Comment: now you've learned how it works here :). Well done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/13781069/2336725

Comment: @Teepeemm: the difference discussed in your link was clear to me. Additionally I needed the information about 'constant expression at compile time' ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

```
'A' + 1
```

is a constant expression. It is known at compile time that the result will fit in a `char`.

Whereas

```
'A' + 787282;
```

will not fit in a `char` and will therefore cause a compilation error.

Answer (score 1):

It is valid because it is a compile time constant expression. Had it been

```
char x;
char y = 'A';
x =  y + 1;
```

The compiler will give you a compile time error, because now it is not a compile time constant expression. But if you will make the variable `y` as `final` the expression will turn again into compile time constant , thus code below will compile.

```
char x;
final char y = 'A';
x =  y + 1;
```

Moral of the story is that when you assign integer to a char , the compiler will allow it as long as it is compiler time constant and it should fit in the range of the `char`.