# String sort descending order using java based on number of times character repeated

Tags: java, string

Here i have two strings that prints each character occurred how many times but i want that result in descending order.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap tm = new TreeMap();
    String s = "ajklfajdlkfajsdklfjalljaklsdfjaklsdjf";
    int[] counts = new int[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch < 128) {
            counts[ch]++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("out of range");
        }
    }
    for (char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
        if (counts[c] != 0) {
            tm.put(counts[c], c);
  //                System.out.println(c + " occured " + counts[c] + "times");
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<tm.size();i++){
        System.out.println(tm.get(i));
    }
   }
```

This code giving output as:null,null,null,s,d but i need ouput as: j l a f k d s .please guide me.

Comment: Have a look at [Character arithmetic in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26077771/character-arithmetic-in-java).

Comment: @PM77-1,here what i'm trying is counting each character how may times occurred then if a character occured 7 times other 6 times any 2 times that i'm displayng 7 6 2 like that.Can you modify my code if possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer is probably rather too like the others but I tried to keep to the spirit of the original code, they were just quicker at writing it.

```
package uk.co.puce4.charactercount;

import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.TreeSet;


public class CharacterCount {
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
    TreeMap<Character,Integer> tm = new TreeMap<Character,Integer>();

    String s = "ajklfajdlkfajsdklfjalljaklsdfjaklsdjf"; 

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) { 
        char ch = s.charAt(i); 
        int count = 1;
        if(tm.containsKey(ch)){
            count=tm.get(ch) + 1;
        }
        tm.put(ch, count);
    }

    TreeSet<CharItem> ts = new TreeSet<CharItem>(); 
    Iterator<Character> it = tm.descendingKeySet().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext()){
        char ch = (char) it.next();
        int count = tm.get(ch);
        CharItem ci= new CharItem(ch, count);
        ts.add(ci);
        }
        Iterator<CharItem> it2 = ts.iterator(); 
        while(it2.hasNext()){
            CharItem ci=it2.next();
            System.out.println(ci.getCh() + " occured " + ci.getCount() + " times"); 
        }
    }
}

class CharItem implements Comparable<CharItem>{
    private int count;
    private char ch;
    public CharItem(char c, int i){
        count = i;
        ch = c;
    }
    public char getCh() {
        return this.ch;
                }
    public int getCount() {
        return this.count;
        }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(CharItem b) {
        return b.count - this.count ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct, but there are a few minor changes to make.

First you should explicitly state the types in generic collections:
TreeMap<Integer, Set<Characters>>

You want to map a count to a set of characters, since there may be two or more characters that appear the same number of times. Otherwise inserting into the map will overwrite the previous count -> char mapping.

Second you want to append your character to the end of a count -> char set if it already exists in the map. The reason is explained above.

Third, a TreeMap of Integers sorts ascending, so refer to the javadoc to see how to get a descending view of your TreeMap.
[Java TreeMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#descendingMap())

Finally, to iterate over a map, you can loop over the entrySet() or values(). Again, checking the javadocs is your best friend.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<Integer, Set<Character>> tm = new TreeMap<Integer, Set<Character>>();
    String s = "ajklfajdlkfajsdklfjalljaklsdfjaklsdjf";
    int[] counts = new int[128];
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        char ch = s.charAt(i);
        if (ch < 128) {
            counts[ch]++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("out of range");
        }
    }
    for (char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
        if (counts[c] != 0) {
            if (tm.contains(counts[c])) {
                // Collision, there's already a character that appeared
                // this number of times
                tm.get(counts[c]).add(c);
            } else {
                Set<Character> charSet = new HashSet<Character>();
                charSet.add(c);
                tm.put(counts[c], charSet);
            }
        }
    }

    NavigableMap<Integer, Set<Character>> descendingMap = tm.descendingMap();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Set<Character>> entry : descendingMap.entrySet()) {
        //int count = entry.getKey();
        Set<Character> chars = entry.getValue();
        for (char c : chars) {
                System.out.println(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Updated to use Set instead of list for efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your approach:

1. You have a `TreeMap` that maps from char count to char. If multiple chars occur with the same count, you'll loose all but 1 of the chars.
2. You use the `get` method of `TreeMap` which means you're getting a char that have occurs `i` times instead of the value of the `i`-th entry in the map.

Here's an alternative for you:

- Create a `Container` class that has fields for the char and the count.
- Use `TreeSet` instead of `TreeMap`.

#### Code:

```
public class StringMap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeSet<Container> ts = new TreeSet<>();
        String s = "ajklfajdlkfajsdklfjalljaklsdfjaklsdjf";
        int[] counts = new int[128];
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            char ch = s.charAt(i);
            if (ch < 128) {
                counts[ch]++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("out of range");
            }
        }
        for (char c = 0; c < 128; c++) {
            if (counts[c] != 0) {
                ts.add(new Container(c, counts[c]));
            }
        }
        for (Container c : ts.descendingSet()) {
            System.out.println(c.character);
        }
    }
}

class Container implements Comparable<Container> {
    
    Container(char c, int count) {
        this.character = c;
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    char character;
    int count;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Container o) {
        int result = Integer.compare(count, o.count);
        return result == 0 ? Character.compare(character, o.character) : result;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        return o instanceof Container && ((Container)o).character == character;
    }
}
```